# Keys on Keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I'm having trouble with my keyboard on my Windows 7 computer. For some reason, some of the buttons are not doing what they are supposed to be doing. For example, the "Play/Pause" button and the "Rewind" button control the volume, while the Volume Up and the Volume Down buttons do nothing. F7 mutes the sound. The buttons that control the screen brightness also do not work. How do I fix this?

Comment: I assume this is a laptop? Please provide make and model.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try CD installation your keyboard. Windows detect main keys.

Comment: And if you no longer have the CD, try the manufacturer website for drivers intended for your laptop or keyboard model #